# For changing a theme name, can I use Grep to find-replace the name in the database and codebase?

Tags: 7, theming, database

For changing a theme name, can I use Grep to find-replace the name in the database and codebase? 
I did this once before, without visible problems on a test site. 
However, I need to be sure that there are no hidden surprises for production sites.

The idea is to

1. download the database and codebase
2. use Grep to find and replace all instances of the theme name (if the themename is not a very general string which is likely to appear elsewhere)
3. replace database and codebase.

Any suggestions or experiences?

Comment: Highly unlikely that will work, mainly because Drupal stores plenty of data in serialised php strings. I’d bet the theme name is in at least one of those. Unless the new and old theme names are identical in length, you’re bound to break the serialisation by doing a blind string replace

Comment: can you just clone your existing theme with all of its files, rename it and all of its functions inside template.tpl, and add is as the new default theme, then remove the old one?